# Why does my second if statement run 2 times in a row after my first if statement is true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, onclick, click

Hello guys I have a problem with my checkRight() function.
I tried to build a quiz webpage with js.
Here is my complete code: https://www.codeply.com/go/qoCnPUDDxG
My questions consists of a class with:  question (string), answers(array of strings) and answer (string) attributes.
If I click on the right answers my counters go very confusing up.

```
function checkRight (){
  $(".answer").click(function() {
       check = $(this).html();
       if(check===qAry[i].rightAnswer){
         rightCounter++;
         $(".richtigZaehler").text(rightCounter);
         i++;
         askQ();
       }
         else if(check!=qAry[i].rightAnswer){
         console.log("Update");
         wrongCounter++;
         $(".falschZaehler").text(wrongCounter);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Your code should be posted *here*, at least enough to show context for the problem you're having. Anyway the problem is that `.click()` adds a new event handler every time it's called, without removing any handlers that already exist. Thus every time `checkRight()` is called another redundant "click" handler is added, and each one will be called when a "click" happens.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the click handler outside? Otherwise you will need to unregister them.

```
var rightCounter=0; //counter for rightAnswer
var wrongCounter=0; //counter for wronganswer

$(".answer").on("click", function() {
 checkRight(this);   
})
```

Then in your checkRight function:

```
function checkRight (evt){
       check = $(evt).html();
       if(check===qAry[i].rightAnswer){
           debugger;
         rightCounter++;
         $(".richtigZaehler").text(rightCounter);
         i++;
         askQ();
       }
         else if(check!=qAry[i].rightAnswer){
         console.log("Update");
         wrongCounter++;
         $(".falschZaehler").text(wrongCounter);
      }
}
```